# How to delete %Userprofile%\AppData?

Tags: windows-7, batch, script, user-profiles

I have got some Windows 7 Machines that more often run out of free space on the Hard drive so I have written a Batch Script to Clean up the C:\Windows\temp, C:\Windows\logs\CBS and the C:\Users Directories, unfortunately I can not delete the AppData folder out of the User-profiles, the Script always shows me the message "The system can not find the specified path.".

-tmrbng

Comment: Why on earth would you want to delete the AppData folder? It contains settings of all programs. True the folder can become large, but if that is a problem, you should highly consider upgrading to a bigger harddisk.

Comment: Deleting that folder is a bad idea. If you have server saved profiles you might run into all kinds of issues and users currently working might lose their settings on more than just that single machine. If you want to clean anything up within the user profiles check the local AppData folder and its temporary directories. You will need administrative privileges (at least) to access those directories. Setting up quotes and similar would probably be a better idea.

Comment: This is most definitely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

Never delete the Application Data folder or AppData, it contains crucial files used by Windows and other Applications. It is also a location for install. If you want to delete the Temp File in AppData delete `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\*`. However, I wouldn't want to delete that either since Windows and Programs are using it all the time for cache files. Many "Cleanup" programs that people download don't do anything really except delete unused things like you are doing. They, in my opinion, have only a converse effect to the effect they are suppose to do.

It is often a great misconception that the least stuff I have on my hard disk the faster it goes. This may seem correct to a normal user, but it is in fact, not. The specs of the device and how many applications are running are the true factors in the game of computer speed. However, one should have more than 5 GB of free space on their disk.

The speed of the Hard Drive: This is often a big one, and is why SSDs or Solid State Drives are so popular. On SSD, the data can quickly be accessed. On an HDD there is an actual disk that spins and a head that has to read the disk. Since this is mechanically slow, SSDs are faster. However some HDD heads are quick enough for the system itself. When you download files they are placed in an empty spot on the drive wherever it can find room; this often causes related files to be scatter in different areas, thus slowing the head. That is why with an HDD, if you are a heavy file user, downloader and installer, you should Defrag your disk often.

The speed of the CPU: Amazingly enough a little above 2GHz is enough to run your system pretty normally without much lag. Here how many and what kind of applications are running is important. Sometimes, especially if you have a Laptop, the power plan (often with Power Saver) can be modified to set a max CPU % usage or speed; As such the max speed will be very low and will cause the System to lag really bad. It should be set a 100% for anything lower than about 2Ghz in my opinion.

How much Ram you have: The more memory you have the better it runs. If you don't have enough Windows will usually create what is called a pagefile (a file that behaves as RAM). But now it is doing twice the work with the hard drive because not it has to access more of it. This is why one should have at least 4GB of Ram and a small pagefile (just in case not enough).

How many Programs and Services are running: If you had every single Windows service enabled and set to automatic for Start Up, your log on to your Word Document or Browser from Shutdown is going to increase dramatically. One because you are starting everything at the same time and you are running multiple things at once. The less things you have open the faster it runs. If you have 5 antiviruses (like some people I know) what do you think it is going to do? Slow the system down even more because it has to load the programs everytime at startup and take a lot of its resources, especially Disk at each wants to scan your hard drive constantly and monitors all interactions done in the computer which Windows is capable of doing itself in Windows Defender. In Task Manager there is a tab where you can enable and disable programs from running at StartUp (do you really need Steam to start up every time, unless you are a big gamer? no.) You can also go to `services.msc` and disable or set to manual things that you know you will not use or runing (Careful, some things are necessary, consult a guide). But you can usually disable almost any third party service or application and it will not harm the workiness of the computah.

EDIT:

If you really want to delete your %userprofile%\AppData folder and destroy the workability of the user profile, then I'd recommend you either log into an Administrator account or boot up into another Operating System or boot into after creating a Windows 7 Repair Disk or Windows Installation Drive.

Open a command prompt with Administrative Privileges and delete it like this:

```
rd /s /q C:\Users\John\AppData
echo Yay I just destroyed a working user profile!
```

Answer (score 0):

Disk defragmentation especially C:/ is equally important in ensuring good performance of your computer in terms of speed.
Ensure your antivirus is not resource intensive..I find Bitdefender quite a good one.
You can still download HBCD to help in most system management.

Comment: Good advice! You just basically summed up my entire answer.

Comment: Details are equally important for the novice